# How to get translated list of all country names in dotnet

Tags: .net-core, localization, translation, cultureinfo

I'm trying to build a dictionary of country names with their two character country code, but with the country name translated to a selected language.

I know the country code for the United Arab Emirates is `AE`, but what would I pass to an `IStringLocalizer` to get it translated?

Could I use something like the following?

```
var localizer = _localizer.WithCulture(new CultureInfo("fr-FR"));
var countryNameTranslated = localizer[103392].ToString();
```

But what I need is the complete list of two character country codes and their (ISO?) numbers, so I can iterate through all of them, using a selected culture code and the localizer to translate them all.

How do I get the complete list of 2 character codes and their numeric codes from the `dotnet core` Microsoft libraries? (Is this even possible?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd recommend two Nuget packages:

- [ISO3166](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ISO3166) by Jorn Schou-Rode
- [IsoNames](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IsoNames) by cmon

Get country name in selected language:

```
IsoNames.CountryNames.GetName(new CultureInfo(language), country);
```

Get list of two letter codes:

```
ISO3166.Country.List.Select(c => c.TwoLetterCode);
```

I looked for some MS stuff previously for similar task and ended up with these two packages.

Comment: I found that this one is much better: https://github.com/nager/Nager.Country